# Multi-Line Cells Latex Table

Tags: tables

I want to make a two column table where each cell has multiple lines, no border line and set table to fit page width. The result should be similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmeyK.png):

[image: this]

How may I achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in a whole host of ways - `minipage`s, `\parbox`es, `tabular`s or other boxes. Here's one using `tabular` and [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) (for convenience, although it's not necessary):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove intercolumn spacing
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\centering}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Item 1 \\ Details of item \\ specification
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Item 2 \\ Details of item \\ specification
  \end{tabular} \\ \\

  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Item 3 \\ Details of item \\ specification
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Item 4 \\ Details of item \\ specification
  \end{tabular} \\ \\

  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Item 5 \\ Details of item \\ specification
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```